# deleting first node in linked list still shows node in results

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having trouble with deleting the first node in my linked list, when i print the results after deleting other nodes its a success, yet deleting the first node, its prints a 0 and the last two members of the struct.

The function is supposed to be passed a pointer to a linked-list, prompt the user for an ID number to find a delete a node, and return the list.

```
struct dog *delete_from_list(struct dog *dogs){

int num;

    printf("Enter a dogs ID number to be deleted ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

struct dog *prev, *cur;

    for(cur = dogs, prev = NULL;
            cur !=NULL && cur->number != num;
            prev = cur, cur = cur->next);

     if (cur == NULL){

            printf("Dog not found");
            return dogs;
    }
     if( prev == NULL){


            dogs = dogs->next;

            printf("Dog deleted");

    }
     else{

            prev->next = cur->next;
    }


    free(cur);


    return dogs;

}
```

This is the function to print the linked list afterwards

```
void print(struct dog *list){

    /* Prints all structs within the
     * linked list
     */


    printf("\nID Number\t Dog Name\t Breed\t\t Owner\n");
    for( ; list != NULL; list = list->next){

            printf("%d\t\t  %-10s\t  %-10s\t %-12s\n", list->number, list->dog_name, list->breed, list->owner_last_name);

    }
```

}

Comment: Please add the code of how you are verifying (_still shows node in results_).

Comment: I added the print function that I am using to print out the list.

Comment: Are you calling as follows? E.g `list = delete_from_list(list);`

Comment: Show the **full** line of how you *call* this. If you're discarding the result rather than saving it as an overwrite to the pointer passed as the parameter, it's wrong.

Comment: I was not calling it as list = delete_from_list(list);

Comment: sorry for idiocy,  Ive been staring at this function for the past hour and never once thought it would of been outside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function apparently works fine works fine (modified it to accept num as a parameter for me...), concerning its actual intention.

What you do not get is an output "dog deleted" if you do not delete the head - this is because you did not implement to do so. Try this instead:

```
if (!cur)
{
    puts("Dog not found");
    return dogs;
}
if(!prev)
{
    dogs = dogs->next;
    puts("head deleted"); // <- changed "dog" -> "head"
}
else
{
    prev->next = cur->next;
    puts("dog deleted"); // <- added by me!
}
```

Important is: You absolutely need to call it (as BLUEPIXIY denoted in his comment) like this:

```
dogs = delete_from_list(dogs);
```

If you do not, your outer variable 'dogs' won't change and will point to memory already deleted. If you still use the then dangling pointer, you get undefined behaviour, most likely an access violation (segmentation fault).

To avoid such a problem, you might like to pass a pointer to pointer to your function. The return value gets free then, and you could use it to indicate if the dog actually could have been removed:

```
bool // need to #include <stdbool.h> for
delete_from_list(struct dog** dogs)
//                          ^
```

You'd now use `*dogs` instead of `dogs` internally and would call it like this:

```
delete_from_list(&dogs);
```

Advantage: user does not have to care about correct re-assignment...